# Probe Neurons in Llama-2 Using Transformers

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, causal-inference

I am attempting to probe neurons for a Llama-2 7B model in order to understand which neurons are activated after a specific prompt.

```
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer

model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

text = "This is a test text"
encoded_input = tokenizer(text,return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**inputs,output_hidden_states=True)
```

However, I am having a hard time interpreting the hidden states, which are represented by **outputs**. My understanding is that Llama-2 7B has 32 transformer layers (which seem to match with the 32 items in **len(outputs[1])**.

My questions are:

1. Which of the items in **outputs** refer to the neurons?
2. How can I see which "neurons" are activated depending on the input prompt?
3. What is the connection between the last hidden state and generated text? Is the last hidden state of **outputs** then fed into an output layer to determine the first word for the response?